# Find the maximum number of valid cartesian coordinates

Tags: greedy-algorithms

Given a list X containing m number of x coordinates and a list Y containing m number of y coordinates. The coordinate (x, y) is valid if and only if the difference between x and y is less than or equal to d. I need to find out the maximum number of valid coordinates. Here is my algorithm.

```
sort the list X in non-decreasing order
sort the list Y in non-decreasing order
for x in X:
     for y in Y:
         if abs(x - y) <= d:
             let x match with y
             remove x from X
             remove y from Y
```

Can this algorithm give me maximum number of valid pairs? If yes, is there any more efficient algorithm? The nested loop means the worst-case time is $O(m^2)$. Is there any log linear time $O(m\log m)$ algorithm for this question?

Comment: If you have them sorted and you fix an $x\in X$, then you need to count the number of $y\in Y$ such that $x-d\leq y\leq x+d$. The indexes of the largest $y$ such that $y\leq x+d$ and the smallest $y$ such that $x-d\leq y$ can be found by binary search. That replaces the inner loop by an $O(\log(m))$ search.

Comment: If the numbers are finite precision floating point I would keep the inequalities in the binary search as $-d\leq x-y$ and $x-y\leq d$. I suspect that they are not equivalent to $y-d\leq x$ and $y\leq x+d$, since the sum of finite precision floating point numbers is not associative.

Comment: It's not clear from your question that you apparently require each $x$ to be matched with at most one $y$ and vice versa. Algorithms for the Assignment Problem will certainly solve this problem optimally; if your algorithm is also optimal (I haven't thought about it enough), then so is an $O(n)$ list merge.